# Java regex find substring in string

Tags: java, regex

I print properties after the application starts up. And I need to hide the values of passwords. I added a new property like:

```
secrets:my.first.password,my.second.password
```

And check each property before printing. If `secrets` contains the key, I replace value to ***. For Example, I have these properties:

```
my.first.name:some name
my.first.password:123
my.second.name:second name
my.second.password:456
secrets:my.first.password,my.second.password
```

I will print the next lines:

```
my.first.name:some name
my.first.password:***
my.second.name:second name
my.second.password:***
secrets:my.first.password,my.second.password
```

I do it with this code(protectedProperties = splitted secrets property):

```
protected String getViewableValue(String key, Object value) {
        if (protectedProperties.contains(key)) {
            return key + ":***";
        } else {
            return key + ":" + value;
        }
    }
```

Now I need to add a new option. I need to hide not only the full key of the property but mask. For example:

```
secrets:my.first.password,*password*
```

It means that all properties with key contain *password* word should be hidden. I wrote this code and it works(I remove * from start and end of word before):

```
protected String getViewableValue(String key, Object value) {
        for (String property : protectedProperties) {
            if (key.contains(property)) return key + ":***";
        }

        return key + ":" + value;
    }
```

But I do not like this solution. I am thinking about regex. Can I change my solution to regex?

Comment: If you need a regex solution, please share the expression and code behind that fail to work.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace All with Regex - substitute with Variable and Substring**

**The Regex:**

```
"my\\.(?:first|second)\\.password:)\\S+"
```

**Regex in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "my.first.name:some name\n"
            + "my.first.password:123\n"
            + "my.second.name:second name\n"
            + "my.second.password:456\n"
            + "secrets:my.first.password,my.second.password\n";

    String result = input
            .replaceAll("(my\\.(?:first|second)\\.password:)\\S+","$1:***");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Output:**

```
my.first.name:some name
my.first.password::***
my.second.name:second name
my.second.password::***
secrets:my.first.password,my.second.password
```